# Heavy resourse utilization - Weblogic server

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, weblogic12c, ubuntu-16.10

I have a server with 4 CPU's and 16GB of RAM. 
There is a Weblogic Admin server and 2 managed servers and a Tomcat server running in this Ubuntu Machine.

The resource utilization explodes at times which is very unusual. This has never happened before and I think it has something to do with the Java Parameters that I used.

Have a look at this:

[image]

### Weblogic Cluster:

Admin Server : qaas-01

Managed Servers : qams-01, qams-02

In the below image you will be able to see that the java processes associated with the above are multiplying and consuming too much memory.

[image]

Figured out that this is more generic and not specific to Weblogic.
A lot of processes are behaving the same way.

In the below picture its Apache Tomcat and Jenkin's slave process thats replicating and consuming memory.

[image]

Can anyone help me identify the real issue?

Comment: Too less details to help.

Comment: please tell me what details you need

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite broad, so start looking into why it may be happening.  Post your JVM flags also and if you changed anything that may be causing this.

First you need to figure out what is taking up your CPU time.

Check weblogic config console to generate a stack trace to see what is going on.  You may need to sit and watch the CPU so you can run that when it spikes.  You can also force a stack trace using jstack.  To get java stacktrace you may need to sudo and execute it as the user running the server otherwise you get OS thread dump which may not be as useful.  Read about jstack.

If above does not give enough info as to why the CPU spiked, and since this is ubuntu you can run:

```
timeout 20 strace -cvf -p {SERVER PID HERE} -o strace_digest.txt
```

This will run strace for 20 seconds and report on which OS calls are being made most frequently.  This can give you a hint as to what is going on.

Enable and check the garbage collection log and see how often it runs, it may not have enough memory.  See if there is a correlation between GC running and CPU spike.

I don't think there is a definitive way to help you solve CPU spike by looking at top, but above is a start to get you debugging.